# Acumatica API clicking the AP billing button for purchase orders

Tags: api, acumatica

Hi when I try to bill a purchase order with Acumaticas API it results in the error

```
{
    "message": "Entity AP301000 not found"
}
```

I have tried using the endpoint entity/Default/20.200.001/AP301000/actions/ReleaseFrom. I have checked the version is correct and there are no errors within the endpoint on Postman. I am also using a PUT method. I did make sure that I am also logged into my company's instance of Acumatica. Is there another way to ensure that the AP billing button of a Purchase order is pressed to add it to the bills and adjustments section of Acumatica? I could not find anything in the API documentation and only found this solution through chatgpt.

EDIT
Lonely oh so Lonely nobody wants to answer me I have no friends.

Comment: This is why chat GPT is replacing stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are using the wrong endpoint, use:

   - POST against {BaseURL}/entity/Default/20.200.001/Bill/ReleaseBill

Make the request body as follows:

```
{
    "entity": {
        "Type": { "value" : "Bill" },
        "ReferenceNbr": { "value" : "YourReferenceNumberHere" },
    },
    "parameters": { }    
}
```